# Match word is not starts with

Tags: php, regex

Regex i tried:

```
:\/
```

This matches but if word starts with `http://` or `https://` it matches too.

My string :

```
:/ ewqeqw eqweqwe qwe http:// ewr ewr erwer ewr:) :/ dasd ewwqeqwe https:// ddfds  :/
```

I want to match `:/` characters except inside `http://` and `https://` strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex would be,

```
(?:http:\/|https:\/)(*SKIP)(*F)|:\/
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/gF5vY6/3)

IT won't match `:/` symbol present inside the strings `http:/` or `https:/`

**OR**

```
(?<!\b):\/
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/gF5vY6/4)

Answer (score 0):

You may want something like:

```
~(?<!\S) :/ (?!\S)~x
```

Which would only match if there are spaces (or beginning/end of string) around the smiley.